# Minecraft portfowarding

Tags: static-ip, minecraft, port-forwarding

I managed to get the Wifi on the raspberry pi to work. However, when I use "hostname -i" in the terminal, it returns something like 127.1.1.1 and when I type "ifconfig" it returns something like "198.168.10.13" and when I use nmap from nmap.org it returns "198.168.10.10". So which one do I use? How do I portfoward? (The youtube videos didn't help, do I have to portfoward to the pi's IP or some other computers?) Also,Is it safe to give out your IP address like I just did? (I tried to make a static IP but I am not sure if I did it correctly, how do I check and, if it is wrong, how do I make a static ip?) Lastly, is vanilla server better then servers like Bukkit? (Sorry for all the questions, I have been working on it for ***weeks***.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address you shall forward is the inet: one from "ifconfig" or "ip a".
It is safe to share this ip, since it is a local ip address.
Also you need to have a public IP address from your ISP to if you want to access the server from outside your network.
To make a static ip on your ethernet, you edit your interfaces file.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And in that file edit eth0 something like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.10.0
    gateway 192.168.10.1
```

You can check what the gateway and network ip is by typing `netstat -nr`